# PHP not displaying errors and POST not working

Tags: php, server, apache2, ubuntu-server

I am developing a web page with an Ubuntu TLS Server 20.04 with apache2. However, I started the page with 000webhost service and PHP worked great. The errors were displayed and my ESP-12f POST requests were working as well.

The thing is that now the errors aren't displayed and the POST is not working. My php code is the following:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
$doorId = $_POST["door"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$data =  $doorId ." ". $id . " " . date("H:i:s d/m/Y") . "\n";
$file =  '../logs/'.$id.'.php';
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

This is a picture comparing both servers actions when this code (`update.php`) is loaded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/laWGP.jpg

Comment: This may be caused be different server settings, probably in php.ini. Try starting wih
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

Comment: Thanks this worked and also gives a reason for post not working

Comment: PS: You should consider filtering your post input data, see https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php. Otherwise you possible let users access your file system in an unwanted/insecure manner, eg. id = '../../bin/' or '../../home/'.

Comment: OK, I'd be very happy then if you acceppt my answer. :-) Glad I could help quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused be different server settings, probably in php.ini. Try starting with

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

You should consider filtering / you have to filter your post input data, see https://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php. Otherwise you possibly let users access your file system in an unwanted/insecure manner, eg. id = '../../bin/...' or '../../home/...'.

All the best!